# ComboBox Item in WPF - Databinding class property with enum value

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, data-binding

I have a CLASS "Uid_Id_Name" and an ENUM "E_UidIdName_Type"

```
public class Uid_Id_Name
{
    public string Uid { get; set; } = "";
    public string Id { get; set; } = "";
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
}

public enum E_UidIdName_Type
{
    Name,
    NameShort
}
```

I have a ComboBox and his items are "Uid_Id_Name"

FIRST item: OK

SECOND item: "{x:Static my:E_UidIdName_Type.Name}" give me the error that must be converted to a string

```
<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Uid"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Uid_Id_Name_Template}">
    <ComboBox.Items >
        <BaseMontanari:Uid_Id_Name Uid="testUID" Id="testID" Name="testNAME"/>
        <BaseMontanari:Uid_Id_Name Uid="{x:Static my:E_UidIdName_Type.Name}" Id="testID2" Name="testNAME2"/>                                        
    </ComboBox.Items>
</ComboBox>
```

How can i convert it ?

I saw similar question but none of them are regarding valorisation of class property with an enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a binding on a CLR property. It has to be a dependency property.

You should *set* the value of your data items programmatically:

```
Uid_Id_Name item = cmb.Items[1] as Uid_Id_Name;
if (item != null)
    item.Uid = E_UidIdName_Type.Name.ToString();
```

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb" SelectedValuePath="Uid" DisplayMemberPath="Uid">
    <ComboBox.Items>
        <BaseMontanari:Uid_Id_Name Uid="testUID" Id="testID" Name="testNAME"/>
        <BaseMontanari:Uid_Id_Name Id="testID2" Name="testNAME2"/>
    </ComboBox.Items>
</ComboBox>
```

XAML is a markup language. You may *display* the enum value using an `ItemTemplate` though:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb" SelectedValuePath="Uid">
    <ComboBox.Items>
        <BaseMontanari:Uid_Id_Name Uid="testUID" Id="testID" Name="testNAME"/>
        <BaseMontanari:Uid_Id_Name Uid="{x:Null}" Id="testID2" Name="testNAME2"/>
    </ComboBox.Items>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Uid}" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Uid}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding 
                                                Source={x:Static my:E_UidIdName_Type.Name}}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: if I cannot , i give up with XAML
I will do it programmatically

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it like this you could use a converter. First you should create one like this:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(E_UidIdName_Type), typeof(string))]
public class ToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value?.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then you have to include your converter in the resources before (don't forget adding the namespace of the converter:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:ToStringConverter Name="ToStringConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

In your ComboBox.Items:

```
<BaseMontanari:Uid_Id_Name Uid="{Binding Source={x:Static my:E_UidIdName_Type.Name}, Converter={StaticResource ToStringConverter}}" Id="testID2" Name="testNAME2"/>
```

Comment: I added the converter, included in the resources (and seems OK)

But doesn't work

Not in the way you wrote


Not even putting the BINDING

Uid="{Binding Source={x:Static my:E_UidIdName_Type.Name}, Converter={StaticResource StandardConverterKey}}"